# what is the upper limit of net.core.somaxconn?

Tags: linux, nginx

I want to increase the maximum number of connections that can be queued for acceptance by NGINX, for this nginx documentation suggested to increase the **somaxconn**.

1) what are the min and max limits?

2) does the limit depend on the system configuration like ram, cores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search mentioned that in old kernels  `net.core.somaxconn` was an unsigned 16 bit integer so **between 0 and 65535**, with a value of 128 as the default and that higher values would silently  get truncated to 65535,  but no mention if/when that was changed and to what.

On my CentOS test system with kernel 3.10.0 still no value beyond 65535 is accepted.

> ```
> sysctl net.core.somaxconn=65536
> sysctl: setting key "net.core.somaxconn": Invalid argument
> ```

I have no idea  what the  real-word impact/requirements are when a large limit is set **and** reached.

Comment: The `listen(2)` man page says: "If a connection request
       arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with an
       indication  of  ECONNREFUSED  or,  if  the underlying protocol supports
       retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt at
       connection succeeds." But if your queue has gotten to 65535 waiting connections, you've got much bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't assign beyond 65,535 because of variable type, so values are bound with data type in C or any other languages. I agree with @HBruijn
{
        struct socket *sock;
        int err, fput_needed;
        int somaxconn;

```
    sock = sockfd_lookup_light(fd, &err, &fput_needed);
    if (sock) {
            somaxconn = sock_net(sock->sk)->core.sysctl_somaxconn;
            if ((unsigned int)backlog > somaxconn)
                    backlog = somaxconn;

            err = security_socket_listen(sock, backlog);
            if (!err)
                    err = sock->ops->listen(sock, backlog);

            fput_light(sock->file, fput_needed);
```

Answer (score 0):

The somaxconn limit was raised to 32 bits (approximately 2 billion) in Linux 4.1 ([patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/becb74f0acca19b5abfcb24dc602530f3deea66a)). For Example, [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 allows a value bigger than 64k](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6439141).

The practical limit would be much smaller, however. Each outstanding socket consumes memory and accepting and processing such a large number of connections also requires cpu and memory.